# Measure server performance

Tags: server, performance

I'm using a shared hosting for my website. How to find out if the performance of the server changes?

I'm asking because my hosting company told me that some other site on the server is slowing down my site because they overloading the server.

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Google Site Speed says Avg. Page Load Time (sec): 15.53 - Is that normal or too high?

Comment: Why is that your problem ? I would insist that they must deal with that other site and provide you with resources that you are paying

Answer (score 2):

They always tell you things like that, it's most often an excuse, and it's the reality of shared hosting I'm afraid.

In general servers get filled up with sites quickly, as performance declines, the hosting company will add new servers to the pool and also manage the contention ratio (i.e. the ratio of heavy users to light users) to spread the load - but there will always be one or more heavy users on a shared host - **that's why it's cheap**.

Some manage this better than others but it really is a case of "you get what you pay for".

- You can do a reverse ip lookup here
  http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/ which
  will tell you how many sites share your servers ip, but [it won't
  tell you how busy each site is](http://www.websitetology.com/?p=806) or if that affects your site's performance (you can make guesses though - but there is nothing you can do about it.
- You can also run tracert from the command line and examine the roundtrip time for a request from
  your site from your location to your server.

If, for example, you're in the UK and your server is in eastern europe then you might find the roundtrip time is long and finding hosting closer to home, or closer to the majority of your users might be more effective than worrying about something outside of your control.

You could also try caching pages, examining your site with Google PageSpeed Insights or YSlow to see if you can make your site more efficient - replacing locally hosted jquery scripts with CDN copies would have a positive effect for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.webpagetest.org/ to measure web site speed, but maybe the best way to track site speed is Google Analytics, under "Content" menu there is a submenu "Site Speed" and there you can see how your site and specific pages are slow (or hopefully fast) in time

Comment: This would be a very poor measure of server performance, it has more to do with the number of objects being downloaded from the server than the speed of the server itself.

Comment: what exactly ? webpagetest.org ?

Comment: Again it's a measure of site performance from a specific location, server performance is one factor in this result but other factors like site build, local internet speeds, database availability and the like would affect these results more than total server load.

Comment: @Antonio Bakula Thanks for the tip! *Google Site Speed* says **Avg. Page Load Time (sec): 15.53** - Is that normal or too high?

Comment: that's is too high

Answer (score 0):

Average page load is very blunt, but 15 seconds is way too high. I'm currently measuring on our system due to performance problems, and the 98th percentile of non-concurrent requests are served in .35 seconds. If you have heavy load or peaks you should measure performance degradation vs. concurrency:

[image: Thanks to Srinath Perera]